# scalaz Foldable compose

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz7

i have a next code

```
val listOption: List[Option[Int]] = List(1.some, none, 2.some)
```

i want to fold elements, i write the next code

```
val result = listx.fold(0.some)((acc, el) => {
  (acc, el) match {
    case (Some(a), Some(b)) => Some(a + b)
    case (Some(a), _) => Some(a)
    case (_, Some(b)) => Some(b)
    case _ => el
  }
})
println(result.getOrElse(0)) // => 3
```

this workds fine, but i see in scalaz sources the next tric

```
val composeFold = Foldable[List] compose Foldable[Option]
composeFold.fold(listOption) // => 3
```

But i do not understand how it correct work, and why scalaz not mix this methods into `listOption` instance, and what differenct between scala `fold` and scalaz `fold`

Answer (score 5):

The scalaz `fold` function uses the `Monoid` instance of the elements, so you don't have to supply a start value and a function to combine the elements.

A `Monoid` has two functions `zero`/`empty` and `append`/`combine`. For `Int` this could be :

```
val intMonoid = new Monoid[Int] {
  def zero = 0
  def append(a: Int, b: => Int) = a + b
}
```

Using this `Monoid[Int]` we can write the Scalaz `fold` as a Scala `fold` :

```
import scalaz.Foldable
import scalaz.std.list._
import scalaz.std.anyVal._

val numbers = List(1,2,3)
Foldable[List].fold(numbers)                          // 6
// analogous to the following Scala fold
numbers.fold(intMonoid.zero)(intMonoid.append(_,_))   // 6
```

We can combine the `Foldable[List]` and `Foldable[Option]` like you showed :

```
import scalaz.std.option._
Foldable[List].fold(List(1,2))    // 3

Foldable[Option].fold(1.some)     // 1
Foldable[Option].fold(none[Int])  // 0

val foldListO = Foldable[List] compose Foldable[Option]
foldListO.fold(List(1.some, none, 2.some))  // 3
```

You can use the `foldable` syntax import and use `concatenate` or `suml`/`sumr` (There is also `fold` but it clashes with `List.fold` and `Option.fold`) :

```
import scalaz.syntax.foldable._
List(1,2,3).concatenate  // 6
1.some.concatenate       // 1

List(1.some, none, 2.some).concatenate.concatenate  // 3
```

---

*Instead of the specific imports like `scalaz.std.list._` and `scalaz.syntax.foldable._`, you could also use the uber imports with `import scalaz._, Scalaz._`.*

Comment: `concatenate` from FoldableSyntax, but in sources i see FoldableSyntax have fold method: `final def fold(implicit A: Monoid[A]): A = F.fold(self)(A)` how i can call fold in foldable syntax instead of fold from scala?